# google url shortener not working with api key via curl in console

Tags: curl, google-url-shortener

I'm trying to curl google url shortener API via command line and getting the following error:

error code: 403

error message: Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.

this is my request:

```
curl -X POST 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIzaSyA5EGsBIvk7TNu_oBFXBeDL5pWOWXXXXXX'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
```

also tried GET:

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=AIzaSyA5EGsBIvk7TNu_oBFXBeDL5pWOWXXXXXX'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
```

curling without API key works fine. My server IP is properly set in Google developers console, API is switched on and I'm not behind any proxy...

Also tried to append the 'userIp' parameter in GET and through -d as documentation suggests, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated..

Thanks.

Comment: _“My server IP is properly set in Google developers console”_ – and you have verified that a cURL request made from your server also uses that very same IP, and is not somehow proxied over another address or something …?

Comment: Sorry about the text formatting, didn't know about the 5 minute limit.

Here's a more understandable text:

tracerouted and added every IP in the list.. still no cigar.. except the * * * ones of course. Also, I have a dev server from which I successfully make the request, which has identical hops(except one, which i included in the allowed IPs list) as the main server.

Comment: Just found this service: http://amibehindaproxy.com/...
It also states that the server is not behind any proxy.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Was hoping there would be an answer to this. Although the fact that removing the API key helped me out for the time being.

Answer (score 7):

So, the answer can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/v1/url/insert

And this is my testing curl command that works:

```
curl https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=YourAPIKeyGoesHere   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{"longUrl": "http://www.google.com/"}'
```